# DatePickerDialog limit option to maximum one week

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I have included the DatePickerDialog into my activity where it allows users to select a calendar month and day. However, I would like to limit the selection only up to a week from now (and no option before the current date).

I have looked into `setMinDate(long minDate) and setMaxDate(long maxDate)`  but have experience difficulties working with those.

Below is the code that allows users to select a date and time

```
btnCalendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalendar);

txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
txtTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTime);

btnCalendar.setOnClickListener(this);
//btnTimePicker.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

if (v == btnCalendar) {

    // Process to get Current Date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Launch Date Picker Dialog
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    // Display Selected date in textbox
                    txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                            + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dpd.show();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. All the best.

**Update:**

```
btnCalendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalendar);

txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
txtTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTime);

btnCalendar.setOnClickListener(this);
//btnTimePicker.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

if (v == btnCalendar) {

    // Process to get Current Date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    // Launch Date Picker Dialog
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Calendar cal=new GregorianCalendar();

                  //min date
                    dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(cal.getTime().getTime()-1000);

                    // max date

                    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 10);
                    Date dte =(Date) cal.getTime();

                    dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(dte.getTime());

                    // Display Selected date in textbox
                    txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                            + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dpd.show();
}
```

the two lines within the above code where I am experiencing an error

```
//min date
                        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(cal.getTime().getTime()-1000);

                        // max date


                        dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(dte.getTime());
```

cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7); if the number is less than 12 than the follow error occurs:

ALL i want to do is to limit the calendar to one week

```
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.CalendarView.onScroll(CalendarView.java:1214)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.CalendarView.access$900(CalendarView.java:76)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.CalendarView$2.onScroll(CalendarView.java:1075)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.AbsListView.invokeOnItemScrollListener(AbsListView.java:1340)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1762)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-30 16:39:07.217: E/AndroidRuntime(2410):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(
```

Comment: Specifically, what are the difficulties with `setMaxDate()` and `setMinDate()`?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I am not sure where to implement it.

Comment: Thanks I have tried incorporating your code but have unfortunately experienced an issue in two lines  I have added an update under my initial post. If you could kindly look into it, that would be helpful.

Comment: at both dpd.getDatePicker, i get Cannot refer to a non-final variable dpd inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: dont set min and max dates in on date set.. you have to write this code in onCreate Dialog itself..

Comment: write code as it is... it will sure work.. bcoz i am using it.. and you are facing error bcoz your varialbe is not global.. define dpd variable at global state..

Comment: thanks the issue was that i was trying to incorporate into an existing code as to keep everything in line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may Help you...
Try This code...

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 


    //  Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month,day);
    Log.i("onCreateDialog", "onCreateDialog : MinDate() : "+new Date().getTime());

    Calendar cal=new GregorianCalendar();

    //min date
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(cal.getTime().getTime()-1000);
    Log.i("onCreateDialog", "onCreateDialog : MinDate() : "+cal.getTime());

    //max date .... added 30 days from currunt date
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
    Date dte =cal.getTime();
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(dte.getTime());
    Log.i("onCreateDialog", "onCreateDialog : MaxDate() : "+dte);

    //customizing calendar view
    dialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(true);
    dialog.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(false);
    dialog.getDatePicker().getCalendarView().setShowWeekNumber(false);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    Log.i("Date", "date : "+System.currentTimeMillis());
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: Hi, It works and thanks. I have been getting an issue were when I tried to change the date from 30 to 7 (one week max), and I have noticed that when the value is less than 12 I always get an unexpected error. I have included an update under the update section of my initial post.